# How to extract the value of an object in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the single value  out of the object output which is "bitcoin" in my case but when i run the code, it only returns me an object pair value.

```
import pandas as pd
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
dflist=pd.DataFrame(cg.get_coins_list()) 

dflist["id"].loc[dflist['symbol'] == "btc"]
```

I tried this following code below but it only return me "true"

```
dflist["id"].loc[dflist['symbol'] == "btc"].all()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51mG2.png)

Comment: all() is used for check if all elements of column have "btc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a view from the dataframe and then just choose an index if you know there's only one output.

```
btc = dflist[dflist['symbol'] == "btc"]
btc.iloc[0]
```

Comment: very helpful. Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Use methods mentioned in the documentation

```
cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd')
```

Output

```
{'bitcoin': {'usd': 3462.04}}
```